# Firefox transition is not working. Is this a bug?

Tags: css, firefox, transition

I have a simple image swap transition that only works on chrome. the code:

```
<a class="twitter" href="index.php"></a>

.twitter {
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
    display:block;
    background:transparent url('../images/twitter.jpg') center top no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    }

.twitter:hover {background-image: url('../images/twitter-hover.jpg');}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gWKEQ/17/

Comment: What kind of background-image transition are you trying to reproduce? A fiddle to demonstrate it would speed up things.

Comment: Place `transition: all 0.3s linear;` above all other browser specific transitions and try again.

Comment: it did not work. here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/gWKEQ/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because only Chrome actually supports animating the `background-image` CSS property - which is actually incorrect according to [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/#the-background-image), where it's noted as:

> **background-image**
>
> Animatable: no

For more info on what you can animate (also in which browsers etc.), check out [**this page**](http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/#background-image). In the future, other browsers will hopefully allow animating the `background-image` property (and the spec will change), since this is something programmers/designers actually want.